# Idèles and reduction modulo $\mathfrak{m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

I am struggling with some "usual" maps in algebraic number theory, but with which I am not used to, confusing a lot of different settings, as idèles, corresponding ideals and reduced images modulo something. And since we sometimes barely define precisely the maps we use, I stay confused. I would like at last to be able to understand as explicitly as possible the involved maps (see below).

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field, I want to grasp quite explicitly the following "natural" maps (I am uncertain of what I write, and will be glad to read every corrections or clarifications you can make):

> $$\mathrm{Ideals \ of \ } \mathcal{O}_K \to \mathbf{A}_{K,f}^\times/K^\times  \to \hat{\mathcal{O}}_K^\times/(1+\mathfrak{m}\hat{\mathcal{O}}_K^\times) \to \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m} \leftarrow \mathbf{Z}/\mathfrak{m}\cap\mathbf{Z}$$

Let us be more precise from now on. Take $\mathfrak{a}$ to be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, the ring of integers of $K$. Write its decomposition into prime ideals:

> $$\mathfrak{a} = \prod_i \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i} \quad \mathrm{\ an \ ideal \ of \ } \mathcal{O}_K$$

We can embed it in the idèles on $K$. For that, I choose local uniformizers $\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ in $K_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ for each $i$, and consider the (is it canonical? could we come back to $\mathfrak{a}$?) image:

> $$x = \prod_i \varpi_{\mathfrak{p}_i}^{e_i} \quad \in \mathbf{A}_{K,f}^\times/K^\times$$

Now, we want to "reduce it modulo an ideal $\mathfrak{m}$" prime to $\mathfrak{a}$, that is to say we consider its image modulo $1+\mathfrak{m}\hat{\mathcal{O}}_K^\times$. But here I get lost and do not understand what "reducing modulo $\mathfrak{m}$ can mean for these ideles...:

> $$\overline{x} = \prod_i \overline{\varpi_{\mathfrak{p}_i}}^{e_i} \quad \in \hat{\mathcal{O}}_K^\times / (1+\mathfrak{m}\hat{\mathcal{O}}_K^\times) \cong \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$$

Back to $\mathcal{O}_K$, denote $x_0$ the image in the last quotient. Now come my embarrassment: there is a natural map $\mathbf{Z}/\mathfrak{m}\cap\mathbf{Z} \to \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ coming from $1 \mapsto 1_K$ (that is to say just viewing $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module), and here is my question:

> **I would like to determine whether or not $x_0$ is in its image, depending on $\mathfrak{a}$**, *i.e.* what can be said about $\mathfrak{a}$, the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ and/or the $e_i$ for having $x_0$ in $\mathbf{Z}/\mathfrak{m}\cap\mathbf{Z}$?

If necessary we can suppose $\mathfrak{m}$ is a power of prime, by Chinese remainder theorem.

Any idea or reference will be really welcome.

(My question could seem in some ways naive or elementary, so I wonder if this question is more suited for MO or MSE, hence I apologize in advance if I am wrong.)

Comment: Are you sure all these maps are correct? For example, there is a canonical surjection $\mathbf A_K^\times/K^\times\to\text{Ideals of }\mathcal O_K$, but I've never seen this map the other way round, and as you say, it looks very non-canonical. Also what is the second right arrow when, for example, $\mathfrak m=0$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 It is in some sense my question: clarifying what those maps are, and it seems they are. For instance, the first one seems to be the one I describe: to an ideal $\prod \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ you associate the idèle $\prod_i \varpi_{\mathfrak{p}_i}^{e_i}$. For $\mathfrak{m}$, it is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$. Does the maps have a sense like that?

Comment: Do you have a reference for where you've seen these maps?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Well, only drafts of works in progress from other people...

Comment: And are you sure all the arrows are the right way round?